# model.setItem() emits signal model.itemChanged() causes loop

Tags: qt, model, pyqt, signals, qtableview

In order to fill `QTableView()` I use `setItem(r, c, item)` method

```
table = QTableView()
model = QStandardItemModel()
table.setModel(model)
item = QStandardItem("some value")
model.setItem(r, c, item)
```

I use it to fill `QTableView()` with data taken from dictionary.
Also if I change items manually directly in `QtableView()` I use signal `itemChanged()` to call a function that performs some actions.

The Problem is that the  `itemChanged()` method is called, also when the item is updated from dictionary. So it causes program looped
Though if I use `model.appendRow([one , two, three])` in order to fill the table, `itemChanged()` doesn't emit signal

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the item data from the GUI use `dataChanged()` signal

Comment: `col_c = table.model().columnCount()
  row_c = table.model().rowCount()
  table.dataChanged(table.model().index(0, 0), table.model().index(row_c - 1, col_c - 1)).connect(self.ChangeDnPItem)
` doesn't work. what do I do wrong?

Comment: `model.dataChanged` causes loop as well

Comment: So, what goes wrong?. In order to fill View() I must use setItem() it calls dataChanged or itemChanged signal. So the loop goes on. Is there any signal that corresponds ONLY for changes in GUI?